# ASP.net Chart Vertical Line for Date which is on X Axis

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have implemented a RangeBar for a Gantt style chart with data from SQL Server:

```
mySelectQuery = "SELECT [DateTime] as StartDate, DATEADD(Day, [Time], [DateTime]) as EndDate, [Type] FROM [TaskTrack] WHERE [User] = '" + User.Identity.Name + "' AND DATEADD(Day, [Time], [DateTime]) >= getdate() ORDER BY [DateTime]";
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dynamic adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySelectQuery, conn);
conn.Open();
adapter.Fill(ds);
Chart1.DataSource = ds;
Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Label = "";
Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Type";
Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "StartDate,EndDate";
Chart1.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "#VALY : #VALX";
Chart1.Series["Series1"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart1.DataBind();
conn.Close();
```

This works really well but along the X Axis are dates and I would like to have a vertical red line pointing up to denote todays date so that when looking at the chart it gives a good indication of when today is and what is to be done for the future.
Does anyone have an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone is getting this issue in the future, I found a solution that works for me:

```
mySelectQuery = "SELECT [DateTime] as StartDate, DATEADD(Day, [Time], [DateTime]) as EndDate, [Type] FROM [TaskTrack] WHERE [User] = '" + User.Identity.Name + "' AND DATEADD(Day, [Time], [DateTime]) >= getdate() ORDER BY [DateTime]";
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dynamic adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySelectQuery, conn);
conn.Open();
adapter.Fill(ds);
Chart1.DataSource = ds;
Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Label = "";
Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Type";
Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "StartDate,EndDate";
Chart1.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "#VALY : #VALX";
Chart1.Series["Series1"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

VerticalLineAnnotation VA;
ChartArea CA;
CA = Chart1.ChartAreas[0];
VA = new VerticalLineAnnotation();
VA.AxisX = CA.AxisX;
VA.AxisY = CA.AxisY;
VA.IsInfinitive = true;
VA.ClipToChartArea = CA.Name;
VA.Name = "myLine";
VA.ToolTip = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
VA.Height = CA.AxisY.Maximum - CA.AxisY.Maximum;

VA.IsInfinitive = true;
VA.ClipToChartArea = CA.Name;

VA.LineColor = Color.Red;
VA.LineWidth = 2;         // use your numbers!
VA.X = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), "dd-MM-yyyy", null).ToOADate();

Chart1.Annotations.Add(VA);

Chart1.DataBind();
conn.Close();
```